# How to understand this algorithm in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

Output of this code is 10, why?

```
$p=5;
for($i=10 ; $i<=20 ; $i++){
    if($i%$p == 0){
        --$p;
    };
    $p++;
}
echo $p;
```

Comment: Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: also, please tag your programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this code, 'p' start at 5. There is also a loop that start at 10, with i as counter and run to 20. For each loop if 'i' is divisible by 'p' then 'p' is minus one. Nonetheless, 'p' is also increasing every loop.

For loop I use number as 'i' value.

loop 10: p = 5 and i divisible by p. Thus, p = 5 - 1 + 1 = 5

loop 11: p = 5 and i not divisible by p. Thus, p = 5 + 1 = 6

loop 12: p = 6 and i divisible by p. Thus, p = 6 + 1 - 1 = 6

loop 13: p = 6 and i not divisible by p. Thus, p = 6 + 1 = 7

loop 14: p = 7 and i divisible by p. Thus, p = 7 + 1 - 1 = 7

... and so on. Thus, p is increase by one every two loops. There are 10 loops. So 'p' is increased by 5.